# Cassandra : can we take node's backup using CSharp Code on windows environment?

Tags: cassandra, ado.net, cqlsh

I have installed Cassandra CQL Client on window 10.but i want to take cassandra node's backup file from CDATA ADO.NET code, which will be stored on specific directory.

I Need help with code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to take node's backup from *Cassandra* `ADO.net` drivers. We can achieve this scenario by *Cassandra* Snapshots for nodes backup.

```
onfluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/basic-git-commands-776639767.html
```